# Hiding raw image destroys it - how to fix it?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, user-interface, rawimage

I wanted to use pop-up type of notification in my project. It was supposed to be hidden on the start, but show up when button is clicked.

So at first I tried `.SetActive(bool)` method, then `.enabled = bool`. Both times it turned out to delete/destroy my raw image at the very beginning of the project run. Below I provide you a snippet of my code:

```cs
void Start()
{
    Notif.enabled = false;
}
private void Outcome()
{
    Notif.enabled = true;
}
```

Comment: what type is `Notif`? Does it still happen if you remove your `Start` method (=> not related to this code at all but happening somewhere else)

Comment: @derHugo well, it was raw image but I decided to change it to just image. The issues still occur

Comment: I suggest you put a component like the following on your object `public class DestroyLog : MonoBehaviour { pivate void OnDestroy() { Debug.LogError("OH NO!", this); } }` .. click on the logged error message and check the stack trace .. it will tell you what exactly caused the deletion of that object

Comment: If "Notif" is an Image component and you set the 'enabled = false' that means the image component will be disabled and not the whole gameobject.